Are values first assigned to variables or are comparisons done first in if statements?
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=4,b=5,x=7;
    if(a=3)
        if (b=0)
            x=10;
    else
        x=0;
    printf("%d\n",x);
    printf("%d\n",b=a);
    return 0;
}

I am currently learning C and I understand that = is for assigning a value to a variable while == is for comparisons; however, I'm not too sure about how the code is run when = is used in an if statement. In the above code, what I think is happening is that as the if statement is run, the values are first assigned then the comparison is done, and thus I don't understand why I get 0 when I print out x. Or is it done the other way round?

Your else "belongs to" the if (b=0)

It's best to use { braces }.

In C 0 is false and anything else is true. There is no "then the comparison is done".

Could you extend this a bit? "values are first assigned then the comparison is done" You do not use a == in your code. Therefore you should tell us what comparison you mean.

I understand that == is for comparison and = is for assigning values, but does the if-statement do anything in this case if = is used?

Your indentation is misleading. With the correct indentation, your code would look like this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=4,b=5,x=7;
    if(a=3)
        if (b=0)
            x=10;
        else
            x=0;
    printf("%d\n",x);
    printf("%d\n",b=a);
    return 0;
}

This is because an else statement always belongs to the most recent if statement, unless you use braces to associate it with a different if statement, for example like this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=4,b=5,x=7;
    if(a=3)
    {
        if (b=0)
        {
            x=10;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        x=0;
    }
    printf("%d\n",x);
    printf("%d\n",b=a);
    return 0;
}

The misleading indentation explains why the output of your program for x is 0 instead of 7.
Most good compilers will warn you about using else without explicit braces in this kind of situation, if you set the compiler warnings to an appropriate level. For example, on the compilers GCC and Clang, you will get a warning similar to this if you have -Wall and -Wextra enabled:
<source>:9:9: warning: add explicit braces to avoid dangling else [-Wdangling-else]
    9 |         else
      |         ^

As a beginner, I suggest that you always use braces (even when not required), in order to prevent such confusion in the future.

In the above code, what I think is happening is that as the if statement is run, the values are first assigned then the comparison is done [...]

This is correct.

I'd recommend "As a C programmer, I suggest that you always use braces (even when not required)". I was once in the code style camp which skips braces when there was only one row following, but that style simply lead to bugs, bugs and more bugs.

In C an assignment has itself a value, which is actually the value that has just been assigned.
Example:
printf("%d\n", a = 3);  // will print 3, and a will contain 3

so this:
if (a = 3)
   printf("Foo\n");

is equivalent to this:
a = 3;
if (a)
   printf("Foo\n");

and therefore the if is pointless here, because anything else than 0 is considered true and therefore the code above boils down to:
a = 3;
printf("Foo\n");

